# trying to load image in TKinter but get white space where it should be any ideas?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, scrollbar, python-imaging-library

i only get one picture at the bottom but theres supposed to be 10 all in a vertical tower any idea? also was wondering if the tkinter scrollbar command could have images inside it if not is there any other way to have a scrollbar for lables?

```
def show_data(self):
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('data OK')
    for i in range(10):
        self.image = Image.open(self.data[i][7] + '.jpg')
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        #result0 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][0])
        #result0.grid(row=i+3, column=1, sticky=W)
        #result1 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][1])
        #result1.grid(row=i+3, column=2, sticky=W)
        #result2 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][2])
        #result2.grid(row=i+3, column=3, sticky=W)
        #result3 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][3])
        #result3.grid(row=i+3, column=4, sticky=W)
        #result4 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][4])
        #result4.grid(row=i+3, column=5, sticky=W)
        #result5 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][5])
        #result5.grid(row=i+3, column=6, sticky=W)
        #result6 = Label(self.frame, text=self.data[i][6])
        #result6.grid(row=i+3, column=7, sticky=W)
        result7 = Label(self.frame, image=self.photo)
        result7.grid(row=i + 3, column=8, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Guess that the code is inside a function, so you use a local variable `photo` to hold the image which will be destroyed once the function exit.  Try using an instance variable instead.

Comment: Yup thanks totally worked, do you also know if i can add a scroll bar to tkinter but have images in the scollbar

Comment: also am i missing something when i put
image = Image.open(self.data[0][7] + '.jpg')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
in the for loop it shows the image in a really wired way in that theres only one ant the bottom instead of 10 along the side

Comment: It is because you have used only one instance variable which get initialized repeatedly inside the for loop.  As in your code, you use same image in the for loop, you can move the image initialization code to outside of the for loop.

Comment: but what if i wanted to change the actual images and replace [0] with [i] otherwise i get 10 of the same image

Comment: The simple way is to attach the image to a instance variable of the associated label.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the image used in label from being destroyed, you need to keep a reference to the image:

```
def show_data(self):
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('data OK')
    for i in range(10):
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.data[i][7]+'.jpg')
        result7 = Label(self.frame, image=photo)
        result7.image = photo # keep a reference of the image
        result7.grid(row=i + 3, column=8, sticky=W)
```

To have a scrollbar for the labels inside a frame, the most common way is to put the frame inside a canvas and then create a scrollbar to scroll the view region of the canvas:

```
# create a canvas and put it as the left side of window
canvas = Canvas(self.master, width=200, height=600) # assume self.master is Tk()
canvas.pack(side='left')
# create an vertical scrollbar and put it at the right side of window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
# configure the scrollbar to scroll the canvas in vertical direction
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
# create the frame as child of canvas to hold the labels
self.frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
# make sure to update the scrolling region if the frame is resized
self.frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))
```

Comment: what if i want the scroll bar on the left side still but im using grid not pack?

Comment: also thanks for the image solution really was hurting my head XD

Comment: You can put the canvas and the scrollbar in a frame and then you can use grid to position the frame.  To put the scrollbar on the left, just change the side options of the scrollbar and the canvas.